# How can i get my colors to print out solid and not half toned?

Tags: colors, laser-printer

I notice that my colors are printing out with little dots like a half tone or newsprint. I've looked in my settings and I don't know how to fix it. I want my colors to be solid. Does this mean my toner is low? I have a Canon ImageCLASS MF 8280Cw.

Comment: Yes..... Your torner is low need to be changed.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/content/faq/?itemid=tcm:14-1061838

Comment: Why on my display does it not tell me my toner is low? How can you tell it's low?

Comment: I doubt the toners is low, more likely your in a toner saver or draft mode, or just a very low resolution.  Nor enough info to answer with fact tho

Answer (score 0):

Most printers can only print 8 solid colours: cyan, magenta, yellow (the 3 colour inks), red, green, blue (mixes of 2 inks), and black and white. All other colours will be halftoned.

Some printers produce finer halftones than others, but the "problem" is always there. With some printers you have some control over the halftoning. For example, if the printer is set to draft mode, halftoning looks coarser. Some applications (e.g. Illustrator) can also control halftoning. However, as desktop printers have lower resolution than printing presses, application control of halftoning is not usually a good idea.